# Controller Actions Return

Tags: php, silverstripe

According to Silverstripe Docs

Action methods can return one of four main things:

- an array. In this case the values in the array are available in the templates and the controller completes as usual by returning a SS_HTTPResponse with the body set to the current template.
- HTML. SilverStripe will wrap the HTML into a SS_HTTPResponse and set the status code to 200.
- an SS_HTTPResponse containing a manually defined status code and body.
- an SS_HTTPResponse_Exception. A special type of response which indicates an error. By returning the exception, the execution pipeline can adapt and display any error handlers.

My question where can I find expanded explanations on these?

Comment: Are you looking for a [link to the docs](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-SS_HTTPResponse.html), or? I'm not sure what kind of expanded explanation you are looking for.

Comment: yes any definitive guide.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you  mean by 'definitive', you could be disappointed. While efforts are made, often a fair chunk of (esp. API) docs get a little out of date from time to time.

Your two sources of docs (short of reading the code verbatim) are:

http://docs.silverstripe.org
http://api.silverstripe.org

I presume you'll want the latter, in which case you'll want to use the search for `Controller::handleRequest` to follow things through I think. You're talking about controller actions, but the same is basically true for any kind of output involving return.

Return: string|array|object.

**String** is basically direct output (but continues through the processing pipeline first, as opposed to eg. `echo 'direct output';`. I believe there are assumptions around the string in terms of header settings (IIRC it defaults to thinking it's HTML, or could have simple heuristic tests), so should be checked on in the API docs/code.

**Array** is a simple shortcut that is effectively the same as returning `$this->customise($thatSameArray);` (use the api link above and search for controller::customise)

**Object** is either a **`RequestHandler`** or a **Response** object (as your snippit says). If a RequestHandler is returned, it is executed (unless it is eg. $this, and already executed). A response is what it says on the tin; an object encapsulating output, including response code, body, etc.

This is all from the top of my head, so should be checked via the above link (which in turn is doxygen style generated documentation, so is contained within the code, but is a step up from reading the code itself).